# Is there a dataset available to fully test a base64 encode/decoder?

Tags: unit-testing, base64

I see that there are many base64 implementations available in the opensource and I found multiple internal implementations in a product that I am maintaining.

I'm trying to factor out duplicates but I am not 100% certain that all these implementations give identical output. Therfore I need to have a dataset that tests all possible combinations of input.

Is that somewhere available ? google search did not really report it.

I saw a similar question on stackoverflow but that one has not been fully answered and it is actually just asking for one phrase (in ascii) that would test all 64 chars. It does not handle padding with = for example. So one test string will certainly not fit the bill for a 100% test.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps something like [Base64Test in Bouncy Castle](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/bouncycastle/util/encoders/Base64Test.java.html) would do what you want?. The tricky part in base64 is handling the padding correctly. It's certainly important to cover that as you mentioned. Accordingly, RFC 4648 specifies these test vectors:

```
   BASE64("") = ""
   BASE64("f") = "Zg=="
   BASE64("fo") = "Zm8="
   BASE64("foo") = "Zm9v"
   BASE64("foob") = "Zm9vYg=="
   BASE64("fooba") = "Zm9vYmE="
   BASE64("foobar") = "Zm9vYmFy"
```

Some of your implementations may produce base64 output that differs only by whether they insert line breaks, and where implementations that break lines insert the break and the line termination used. You would have to do additional testing to determine whether you can safely replace an implementation that's using one style with a different one. In particular, a decoder might make assumptions about line length or termination.

Comment: The test in bouncy castle is a bit a bad practice in unit testing. It is generating random data and then checking encode-decode that they endup with the original random data.

Comment: I agree. My own unit tests use the RFC 4648 strings and several carefully constructed long strings that include control characters. I

Comment: (hit submit by accident) I mentioned the Bouncy Castle tests because you wanted to test all characters. While a big chunk of random data isn't guaranteed to contain every character, it's more likely to break an implementation than static data built by hand. True, the round trip smells a bit, but in actuality, it's unlikely the encoder and decoder have complementary errors. In my experience implementing a couple of encoders similar to base64 (some legal printable characters had to be excluded) a broken encoder makes garbage and running that garbage through a broken decoder makes gibberish.

Comment: To be clear, I would run the same random data through all the decoders and test that they produced the same output, or with acceptable differences in line endings.